# for a given path between node u-v in tree find maximum XOR with any node in that path

Tags: algorithm, tree, xor

For a Given a tree, there are certain `1<=q<=10^5` queries. Each query has nodes `u`, `v` and `K`. How to find `max(K`XOR`node)` where `node` is any node lying in the path between node u and v. Where XOR is bitwise `XOR` operation.

Any help, what will be an optimal way of performing the queries for a number of times.

Answer (score 1):

It is similar to this question [Maximum XOR value faster than just using XOR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10734334/maximum-xor-value-faster-than-just-using-xor). But queries on the tree. This solution is offline. For every query answer will be `max(getxor(LCA(u, v), u, K), getxor(LCA(u, v), v, K))`. Perform dfs. When entering node add it to the trie, when leaving erase. In each node of trie store level of node. Then answering to this query can be a simple walk through this trie. To check whether there is suitable prefix higer or equal `level[LCA(u, v)]` you should do a binary search over stored array in a node.
The algorithm complexity is `O(log(n) * log(max_node_val))`